# How to redirect a particular country IP to a particular website landing page without share location alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect, location

I want to redirect the visitors from Australian IP to a particular domain landing page. If the visitor of Australian IP hit a domain server URL from any browser address bar, then the URL change & redirect to the same domain another location folder. I want to implement this requirement with a JavaScript or jQuery code for the normal HTML page. (Not any dynamic page)

For example, my website is "www.example.com" & I want to redirect all the Australian countries IP to "www.example.com/aus", But I don't want to share my location when hit the URL into browser address bar, which came up when we going to implement with geolocation tracking with a location share alert box. Can anyone help me or reconstruct a script to make it work for its purpose? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Get the country code by using [ipgeolocation.io](https://ipgeolocation.io/) API, then redirect the Australian visitors to [www.example.com/aus](http://www.example.com/aus). The following code will help you a lot.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    request.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    if (4 === this.readyState && 200 === this.status) { 
    var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText); 
    if (json.country_code2 == "AU" && window.location.hostname !== "http://www.example.com/aus") { 
    window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/aus"; 
    }else { 
    window.location.href = "https://www.exmaple.com"; 
    } 
    } 
    } 
    request.open("GET", "https ://api.ipgeolocation.io/ipgeo?apiKey=YOUR_API_KEY&fields=country_code2", false); 
    request.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json"); 
    request.send();
```

Comment: can I use this API's free plan in the production?

Comment: Yes, you can use ipgeolocation.io API free plan. It offers 1000 requests/day.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Country code using `ipinfo.io` and compare with end user country if match further your process.

```js
$.get("https://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
  var Coutntry_Code = response.country;
  var url = window.location.href;
  //var country = url.split(/[\s/]+/); // You Get country code from url
  var country = 'us' // Set value for test. Comment this line and uncomment above line in your project.
  if (Coutntry_Code === country) {
    alert('Your url to redirect');
  } else {
    alert('Your another url to redirect or block page');
  }
}, "jsonp");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```